# Debugging on the remote cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I have a program which works fine in a local cluster but not running properly when executing in on the remote cluster. I would like to know, what are the best and common ways of debugging a program running on a remote Flink cluster?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to debug a Flink application on a remote cluster.
Since using a real debugger is complicated, I would first try to log as much as possible to find out the error.

Another approach that could be helpful is using Flink's accumulators. With them, you can gather some statistics: For example when you have a filter, you can determine, how many elements passed the filter and so on.

The last resort is attaching a debugger to one of the Flink TaskManager JVMs.

Also check out my presentation on the topic: http://de.slideshare.net/robertmetzger1/apache-flink-hands-on